# Form Library datasheet view value disappears on tab off

Tags: 2016, datasheet, infopath-form

I am working in SharePoint 2016 on Premises. Using InfoPath designer 2013, I published an InfoPath form to a library.  The form works fine when editing values in the browser. I created a datasheet view so my client may edit a single field with the word Approved.  It is represented in the form as an option button. I am able to write into the field fine, but when I tab off the field, it flashes and the value disappears.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my issue has to do with entries made before I added the column.  If I create a new entry in my form, the value remains. It doesn’t remain for entries there beforehand. I neglected to share that in my question. For prior entries, I need to edit the form itself to set the value.